# Is there a preprocessor option to check for the availability of hdf5?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, hdf5

To switch hdf5-support on, I currently have in the preprocessor

```c
#define HDF5
#ifdef HDF5
    #include "hdf5.h"
#endif
```

This means, I have to manually active the `#define HDF5` line (like in the code-snippet given above) or de-activate it (by deleting it or putting comment characters in-front of it). Is there something better like `#ifdef _HDF5` to check for my compiler options (using gcc) ?

For openmp, for example, I have

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
#endif
```

which means that the `omp.h` file is only included, when an appropriate compiler flag was set. I was hoping for something similar for hdf5 but could find nothing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC has a `-D` option to make processor macros outside of the code.

```
gcc -DHDF5 source.c
```

will make `#ifdef HDF5` true.

Comment: All relevant compilers do have such a flag (might be called differently, e.g. MSVC++ has `/D`)

Comment: well, thanks a lot for pointing me to such an important and useful concept ;-)